# How can I send comma before down in Autohotkey (AHK)?

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I want to make an AHK script to do the following: 
After writing a hotstring, repeat for ever: 
Send a comma 
Send down arrow 
My current code is this:

```
::startthisthingnow::
while True
    Send, {,}
    Send, {Down}
```

But it only sends unlimited commas after each other, like: 
`,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either place all sends in one line:

```
Send, {,}{Down}
```

or include the second Send in the loop:

```
while True{
  Send, {,}
  Send, {Down}
}
```